# Best way to manage y/n and password prompts through a Python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

I am creating a Python script to install AUR packages but can't figure out how to detect yes/no and root password prompts.

So far what I have managed is to get rid of yes/no prompts using `yes` command, like this.

```
cmd = r'yes y | makepkg -si'
output = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
```

But still 2 problems persist:

1. **Detect the password prompt**: The password prompt appears mainly after `makepkg` enters in fakeroot. IDK how to detect that and supply the password from the script. There is no pattern actually. Some package evoke 1 y/n prompt while some prompt more than 1.
2. **Enter actual password**: Actually, I want to enter password through a GUI. So, basically, I want user to input password in a text box that I will create using Tkinter.

   tkinter.simpledialog.askstring("Password", "Enter password:", show='*')

I am confused how to implement this. I looked up this problem already and some Stack Overflow posts demonstrate the use of `pexpect` but I am having hard time understanding it. But if it can be done using the standard libraries then it would be great.

Comment: This is usually the kind of things people use `expect` for.

Comment: @they But this is not built in or is it ? And does it take a prompt to identify via pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Detect the password prompt: The password prompt appears mainly after makepkg enters in fakeroot. IDK how to detect that and supply the password from the script. There is no pattern actually. Some package evoke 1 y/n prompt while some prompt more than 1.

There is a pattern. An y/n prompt is shown when:

- makepkg invokes pacman to install build dependencies (for the `-s` option);
- makepkg invokes pacman to install the freshly built package (for the `-i` option);
- makepkg invokes pacman to remove the build dependencies (for the `-r` option).
- *makepkg invokes pacman to...*

In all cases, if makepkg is given the `--noconfirm` option, it will pass that to pacman as well.

> Enter actual password: Actually, I want to enter password through a GUI. So, basically, I want user to input password in a text box that I will create using Tkinter.

The password prompt, if any, is shown by *sudo*. Sudo supports running external "askpass" tools through the `SUDO_ASKPASS` environment variable.

Write or install a program that shows the password prompt and outputs the password to stdout (e.g. ssh-askpass or zenity would do), then set the `SUDO_ASKPASS` environment variable to the program's path:

```
export SUDO_ASKPASS=/usr/local/bin/ssh-askpass
```

Finally, edit `~/.config/pacman/makepkg.conf` to make makepkg run `sudo -A` for elevation, activating the "graphical askpass" feature:

```
PACMAN_AUTH=(sudo -A)
```

Comment: Thanks. Although I haven't tried it now but it seems promising.